# loopbackjs explorer behind reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have loopbackjs with the (swagger) explorer enabled running behind a **reverse proxy** (nginx)

- loopbackjs is running ok
- explorer loads fine

but the **[try it out!] buttons are pointing to the internal address** (127.0.0.1:300) instead of pointing to https://db.mydomain.com/api/.......

Cannot find any clue in the doc, nor in google.

Reverse engineered the code, but got stuck.

There is a URL you can modify in the options, but this does not do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Created a workaround by configuring an ssh tunnel on localhost:3000 to db.mydomain.com:80. This is ok for developing but still has to be solved for the production environment.

Comment: I remember trying to do the same thing and giving up because the loopback did not support it. One option would be to generate the swagger file (`lb export-api-def -o swagger.yaml`)and host it separately after modifying it however you wish.